# Magento 2 - Making categories in Layered Navigation link, instead of filter

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have a category with some subcategories:

```
- Lamps
-- Hanging lamps
-- Wall lamps
-- Floor lamps
```

When clicking on one of the three subcategories in the Layered Navigation, the product listing is filtered to the products of that specific category. I don't want it to filter, but I want the subcategories in the Layered Navigation to actually link to the category.

Is this a Magento 2 setting, or does this require custom changes? If so, can anybody help me get started? I've done some searching, but was only able to find a similar question for Magento 1.

Comment: The products are not being filtered.It shows you the product which you add in the category from the backend.

Comment: And why would you want all the products which are not Hanging lamps (lets say you have navigated to it) to be displayed under that category?

Comment: Hi Shabbir, thanks for the response. I think there's a little miscommunication here.

When clicking on a category in the Layered Navigation, the product listing is really being filtered. For example in category 'Meubels' (furniture), I have a subcategory 'Stoelen' (chairs). When clicking on 'Stoelen' in the Layered Navigation, this happens:

https://i.imgur.com/J44gJzS.png
The URL looks like: /meubels?cat=51

I don't want it to 'filter' the listing on-page, I want it to link to the actual 'Stoelen' category. It should be linking to /meubels/stoelen/ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a custom plugin class. Where you can change the core behavior of `getUrl` method in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item` class. Because this `getUrl` method is responsible for generating all filter URLs.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Magento_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Item.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter;

class Item
{
    protected $categoryHelper;
    protected $categoryRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
    ) {
        $this->categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

    public function afterGetUrl(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        // custom url for category filter
        if ($subject->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == 'cat') {
            $categoryId = $subject->getValue();
            $categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
            return $this->categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($categoryObj);
        }
        
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Here `after` plugin method (`afterGetUrl`) is used. Which runs after the main method (`getUrl`).

If you want to know more about plugin class. You can check [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).

Comment: I'm sorry for the delayed answer. Once again Milan, I don't know how to thank you enough! This helps me just perfectly. My eyes felt on a plug-in that could do this for me, but the costs were $300+, but that definitely isn't worth it for such a small project. You're a legend.

Comment: While technically workable, this solution is very inefficient and will load each subcategory individually, meaning a new DB read for each one, which will be slow.  A better solution would be to get all filter values earlier on in the rendering and fetch all categories in one go - although don't know the best plugin point for this off the top of my head

Comment: While technically workable, this solution is very inefficient and will load each subcategory individually, meaning a new DB read for each one, which will be slow.  A better solution would be to get all filter values earlier on in the rendering and fetch all categories in one go - although don't know the best plugin point for this off the top of my head

Answer (score 1):

I am working on magento 2.3.3 - 2.3.4 and this solution does not work for me,
but it was very helpful. I need to change the code little bit.

here is my fix:

```php
    <?php namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter;

       class Item
       {
           protected $categoryHelper;
           protected $categoryRepository;

           public function __construct(
               \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
               \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
           ) {
               $this->categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
               $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
           }

           public function afterGetUrl(
               \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item $subject, $result
           ) {
               // custom url for category filter
               if (strtolower($subject->getFilter()->getRequestVar()) === 'cat') {
                   $categoryId = $subject->getValue();
                   $categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
                   return $this->categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($categoryObj);
               }

               return $result;
           }
       }
```

I hope it will be helpful as it was for me.